# how to insert protocol in Lyx?

Tags: floats, lyx, algorithms

I know how to insert "algorithm" in Lyx. But how to insert "protocol" as shown in the following figure?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to produce a type of figure which is refered as "Protocol"? Or how to produce the content?

Comment: My question is how to produce a type of figure which is referred as "Protocol".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `algorithm` and `algorithmic` to generate the protocol. 
more info [here](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/presenting-algorithmsprotocols-in-neat.html) and [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms).

To do the Protocols "preamble" (Party, input and so on) I would use a simple tabular.

The final outcome would be something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}  %need these for the protocol
\usepackage{array}        % this package for the tabular


\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.8cm}} %this is to create a nice tabular, you can tweek this, or tweek the tabular directly

\begin {document}
blah blah blah
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\floatname{algorithm}{Protocol} %define the title to be protocol
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}
\caption{Something about integers}
\label{protocol1}
\begin{tabular}{LLL} %define the party, input and so on
 Party &$A$ &$B$\\
 Hard &tada &woohoo\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{algorithmic}[1] %state the steps
\STATE $A$ chooses a random number $r$ of $\log_{2}N-1$ bits, encrypts it, and computes...
\STATE $B$ dectypts $\left[z\right]$...
\STATE $A$ and $B$ do something...\\
That is long\\
and takes up space\\
\STATE $B$ computes...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

To do this in Lyx all you have to do is add the lines with three packages (`algorithm`,`algorithmic` and `array`) and the one with `newcolumntype` to your documents preamble (document->settings->preamble).

Then in the body of the text add in ERT (cntrl +l) the float (everything from `\begin{algorithm}...` wherever you want it to be.

Notice that the float is placed "Here definately" by using the `[H]` option. you might want to change it to something more suitable like `[htb]`.

Alternatively you could insert an algorithm float, in the float insert table, then after the table add the algorithmic with ERT.

Comment: Note that the OP uses LyX, which is not a LaTeX editor per se, so code-only  answers may or may not be useful, depending on the user.

Comment: You are right... I added some explanations in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: use the package newfloat.

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{newfloat, blindtext}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
fileext=lop,
listname={List of Protocols},
name=Protocol,
placement=p,
within=section,
%chapterlistsgaps=off,
]{protocoll} 


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{protocoll}
\caption{Exact integer division}
  \begin{tabular}{lr}
    Here & is the content\\
  \end{tabular}

\end{protocoll}

\end{document}
```

In Lyx you can add LaTeX-code to your document, I assume that you know that.